# Height & width % not doing anything

Tags: html

Hey I'm stuck on a code with CSS, I'm trying to make a certain div 100% of the height and 25% of the width of the page and fill it up with a background, but it only works if there is text entered and it will adjust itself to the height of the text, not the page.

Hope someone could help me with this.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<head>
    <title>Height test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">kaas</div>
</body>
```

style.css

```
   body{
    background:#fff;
}

#menu{
    background:#000;
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Remy

Comment: Your index page is incomplete, and there is no html root tag,
html is the window, your can then assign body to be 100% of that

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a DIV to 100%, it is going to adjust to the content of it. In this brief example you're showing up, there's no content, so 100% of nothing is nothing.

If you want this div to be based on the page size, you must specify it.

```
body{
    width:900px;  //example values 
    height:500px; //example values
}

#menu{
    background:#000;
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
}
```

And I would recommend you to create another div to treat the page in general.

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="menu">kaas</div>
    </div
</body>
```

and then:

```
#page{
    width:900px;  //example values 
    height:500px; //example values
}

#menu{
    background:#000;
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
}
```